# Create new "Item" and all associated properties

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Product Table and a Recipe Table with a foreign key linking the tables using product table->ID, and I am wondering if I can create the Product and add the recipe at the same time or the only way is to create the Product and then add the recipes in a different view.

I have looked online for a similar scenario with no success.

Comment: you cant put some code pls?

Comment: To be honest there is no code as I have been scratching my head to figure out how I would capture the ID from the product table and use it in the recipe as a foreign key. I just want to know if it is possible and if so what's the theory behind it, to give me a solid base to start coding it. thx

Comment: `if I can create the Product and add the recipe at the same time` => If this is from a UI point of view, then sure. If this is from a DB point of view, then always parent first before child. So, insertion in product table will take place first and then the receipe with product's primary key.

Comment: From the user point of view it will be seamless, but from the DB point of view would I be doing 2 inserts ?. 1 - Insert new item to product. 2- get lastinsertid(). 3. insert the recipes using the lastinsertid()?. Does that sound right ?

Comment: Hi Dave; Thanks for the comment but I am not asking for codes to be written, I am asking for a method or the method I just mentioned to be acceptable as a possible solution to what I am trying to achieve. at least that would give me a starting point to write the code.

Comment: You should really thoroughly read through [ask] and several of the other links @Dave provided to you.  This question is entirely too broad, without a specific issue, and example (including a [mcve], which is applicable in this case) with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys figured it out .. 
Saved the recipe first and then got the last ID from the saved recipe
and then saved the associated material with the percentage.

```
  $recipe = new Recipe([
        'name' =>$request->get('name'),
        'description' => $request ->get('description')
    ]);
    $recipe ->save(); // Save the above and get the ID

    $recipematerial= new RecipeMaterial([
        'material_id' => $request ->get('material'),
        'recipe_id' => $recipe->id,
        'percentage' => $request ->get('percentage')
    ]);
    $recipematerial ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have define relation ship in your Model.

you can use attach method to add data related table.

```
$recipe = $request->get('recipe');
$product =   $request->get('product')        
$product = New Product();
$product = $product->create($product);
if($product){
    $product->recipe()->attach($recipe); 
}
```